# How to handle an extremely large database table size?

Tags: sql, database, crm

[image]

In this scenario, every sales order is going to have atleast 400-500 products associated with it. Now everytime a sales order is generated, the cost and price of those products will be saved in the SalesOrderProduct table. This will cause the SalesOrderProduct table to become extremely large in a short period of time. Whats the best way to handle the size of this table?

Comment: Values from the SalesOrderProduct table will be accessed when someone opens up an existing sales order, which will not happen that often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure there is a problem?

If you have millions of rows, no sweat. A SQL database will chew that stuff up.

If you have billions of rows, you might want a key-value store instead of a SQL database. Especially for archival information like past orders which is write-once read-never (and analyze-rarely). If you can't switch from SQL, you can use a clustered database.

But before you do anything, be sure there's an issue - test the performance with a good, realistic workload. See if it'll handle your needs for the near future. Don't solve problems which aren't there.

Final note: for this *particular* database schema, you can eliminate the SalesOrderProduct table by keeping track of historical costs/prices for products. Then you can use the order date to backfigure the costs/prices of all ordered products, eliminating the need for that join table.

Comment: SalesOrderProduct is still needed to associate orders and products.  Cost and price can be eliminated in favor of historical pricing, but only if they're not configured separately for each order (which is a possibility).

Comment: @Larry Lustig: If you have per-order overrides, you could insert them into the table. But I'd assume historical pricing would eliminate the vast majority of the orders. At any rate, that's an aside - the interesting question to me here is "does it scale?".

Comment: @LarryLustig Cost and Price cannot be eliminated, because I want to record the price of a particualr product for every sales order to maintain its integrity.

Comment: @mvador: What I was trying to say there is that, if you know what the price *was* on a particular day, and you know the day on which the order was placed, then you know what the price was in the order (unless that particular order had a special price not offered elsewhere). So you only need to store the record of historical *prices*, not historical *order prices*.

Comment: @Borealid The cost of the product will be the same for every sales order created on a particular day but the price will be different based on if its a governent project, residential or commercial. But yes what you said makes sense to me now.